# Is there a way to hide the scrollbars in IE8?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer

do you know whether there is a way to not let the scrollbars in IE8 appear?
I've got a complete empty .html site and loaded it in IE8 and scrollbars are appearing.

I've been searching the net for a while, but couldn't find any hint. Is it solveable with CSS or do I need Javascript?

Every hint is much appreciated.

Comment: You didn't find this then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964717

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use the CSS [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) property to hide the scrollbars:

```
html, body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need this to hide scrollbars for a page that doesn't need them - just a proper doctype.

Answer (score 6):

If your blank HTML page is standards-compliant (to some degree I suppose), IE8 will not display scrollbars. You shouldn't need any CSS. Here's a sample page that won't have scrollbars:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>hello</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

If IE8 renders the page in Quirks Mode, it will always have scroll bars. You can check exactly what rendering it's using (and test different renderings) in the Developer Tools window (press F12). The "Browser Mode" and "Document Mode" settings at the end of the menu bar will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing `overflow:hidden;` in your css file, in the body,html tags.