# Overflow: auto on a DIV with a child TABLE scroll bar stays around when elements are removed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

In IE8 when dynamically removing TR elements from a table inside a DIV with a static height and overflow set to auto the scroll bar remains visible when its not needed anymore.

Here is a an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9HGJm/17/

Is there a way get IE to hide the scroll bar when its not needed anymore as other browsers do?

Comment: Seems to be very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964717/removing-page-scrollbars-in-ie8-overflowhidden-not-working - IE8 Standards vs. Quirks mode; have you tried adding/modifying your DOCTYPE?

Comment: The site has a doctype declared and is rending in IE8 Standards mode with this issue. The scroll bar actually goes away as expected in quirks mode but that is not an acceptable solution.

Comment: This is a bit of a hack, but it does make it work in IE8. http://jsfiddle.net/9HGJm/7/ Leaving the code as I have it works in Chrome, IE8, IE9. But in IE7... you get a weird issue where it adds the bottom scroll bar... but your code works fine in IE7. It's not a complete solution but it might help towards one, which is why I'm posting this as a comment instead of an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Foobar's approach by manually changing the overflow property. Appears to be the only way to get IE8 to cooperate.

```
      if ( $('#container> div').height() <= $('.selectionData').height() ) {
              $('#container').css('overflow','visible');
        } else {
              $('#container').css('overflow','auto');           
       }
```

Here is an example of the result: http://jsfiddle.net/9HGJm/7/

Answer (score 0):

Removing the fixed width set on the #macroFilters div seemed to help make the scrollbar go away. Another way was that I added a parent div to wrap the #macroFilters div and then set that outer div to a fixed width and the scrollbar went away as well.

Comment: I updated the fiddle with this but the scroll bar still sticks around
http://jsfiddle.net/kXH33/

Comment: Hmm, I just tried your code in my IE9, but using IE8 browser mode, and the scroll bar disappears.

Comment: The browser mode is never exactly the same as using the actual version, it definitely sticks around in IE8