# How to hide scroll bar of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a scrolling div and I want to hide the scroll bar but still be able to scroll without problems in IE8+.

I made this example code -> http://codepen.io/celicoo/pen/emqJoz

And here is the code:

HTML:

```
<div id="site">
    <div class="container_scrolling">
        <div class="container_hidden">
            <div class="box">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#site * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    border: 0;
}
#site {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2000px;
    color: #a3265e;
}
#site .container_scrolling {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#site .container_hidden {
    height: 2810px;
    width: 100%;
}
#site .box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -75px;
}
```

I've found several examples, but I can't change the HTML structure of my application.

Comment: What DOCTYPE are you using?

Comment: just <!DOCTYPE html>, why?? :B.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe there is a way to achieve scrolling without scrollbars in IE8, but you may be able to use a jquery plugin to do so

https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

as per my comment, if you want to hide scrollbars in IE8, you have to use a different DOCTYPE:

[removing page scrollbars in IE8 (overflow:hidden not working)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964717/removing-page-scrollbars-in-ie8-overflowhidden-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Also depending on how you are declaring the page, IE will either render it in standard or quirks mode.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Should remove the scrollbar.

Comment: overflow:hidden will stop the scrolling.. :/

Comment: Here is a good blog that may help you out. He seems to be talking about the same issue. 

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kurlak/archive/2013/11/03/hiding-vertical-scrollbars-with-pure-css-in-chrome-ie-6-firefox-opera-and-safari.aspx